# Problema al Querer Crear un Clase de Consulta Android Studio SQL

Tags: android

Mi Problema en el Dia de Hoy es que e estado desarrollando una APP
que tiene un Login, Un Mantenimiento Productos (Para mas no decir), todo con el motor de base de datos SQL

ya cree el login todo Ok, Hace el procedimeinto de un logeo normal con usuario y pass, tambien cree el mantenimiento de crear productos, donde cojo como parametros
el nombre del producto y su respectiva descripción, agrego, edito, y elimino, solo que no hace la gestion de buscar los datos y mostrarmelo cuando acceso al layout correspondiente, mediante el metodo onCreate de mi MainMenu
pero bueno ese no es el caso
el caso correspondiente es es que deseo saber como hago
que mediante un botón, me busque los nombres que dijite o tienen relación al edittext del nombre,
e intentado hacerlo mediante el siguiente código:

```
package com.sqldata.gst.appsql;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Created by Administrador on 05/10/2016.
 */

public class ConClientes extends MainActivity {
    Conexion conexionSQL;
    EditText txtCdCliente, txtNomCli;
    Button btnBuscar, btnRetornar;
    ProgressBar pgrCliente;
    ListView lstClientes;
    String idCliente;
    //ResultSet rs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.con_clientes);

        conexionSQL = new Conexion();
        txtCdCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCdCliente);
        //txtNomCli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNomCli);
        btnBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
        btnRetornar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRetornar);
        pgrCliente = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pgrCliente);
        lstClientes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstClientes);
        pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        idCliente = "";

        // Evento Ejecutar Boton
        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SelectClientes selectClientes = new SelectClientes();
                selectClientes.execute(""); //Cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.String)
            }
        });
    }

    public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String result = "";

        List<Map<String, String>> CliList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(ConClientes.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String[] from = {"A", "B", "C"};
            int[] views = {R.id.lblClienteId, R.id.lblNomCli, R.id.lblCodCli};
            final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(ConClientes.this, CliList, R.layout.lst_cliente,
                    from, views);
            lstClientes.setAdapter(ADA);

            lstClientes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA.getItem(arg2);
                    idCliente = (String) obj.get("A");
                    //String ClienName = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String ClienCod = (String) obj.get("C");
                    //txtNomCli.setText(ClienName);
                    txtCdCliente.setText(ClienCod);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (String... params){
            try{
                Connection cnSQL = conexionSQL.CONN();
                if (cnSQL == null){
                    result = "Error en la Conexión SQL Server";
                }
                else{
                    String query = "select * from clientes";
                    PreparedStatement psSQL = cnSQL.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rsSQL = psSQL.executeQuery();

                    ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList();
                    while (rsSQL.next()){
                        Map<String, String> dataRec = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        dataRec.put("A", rsSQL.getString("idcliente"));
                        dataRec.put("B", rsSQL.getString("nom_cli"));
                        dataRec.put("C", rsSQL.getString("cod_cli"));
                        CliList.add(dataRec);
                    }
                    result = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex){
                result = "Error al Buscar Datos de la Tabla Clientes";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class SelectClientes extends ArrayList<String>{

        String result = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        String ClienCod = txtCdCliente.getText().toString();
        String NomCli = txtNomCli.getText().toString();

        @Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(ConClientes.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (isSuccess == true){
                FillList fillList = new FillList();
                fillList.execute("");
            }
        }

        @Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            if (ClienCod.trim().equals(""))
                result = "Favor de Introducir el Codigo del Cliente";
            else {
                try{
                    Connection con = conexionSQL.CONN();
                    if (con == null){
                        result = "No Hay Datos para Mostrar";
                    } else {
                        String query = "Select * from clientes where idcliente =" + idCliente;
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                        result = "Busqueda de Datos Correcta";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    isSuccess = false;
                    result = "Verifique los Datos";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


    }
}
```

Pues bien como observan ese es mi codigo que e intentado realizar pero tiene dos factores de codigo
los que estan comentados
el primero es el:

```
selectClientes.execute(""); //Cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.String)
```

y el segundo en los Override

```
@Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
```

ese es mi problemita que no entiendo como puedo hacerlo para que me haga la consulta constando del editext = que sera el nombre que buscare o los nombres, y el botón que ejecutara la acción de select * from, ya me entienden

y al paso desearía como puedo hacer que al momento de entrar al layout desde el menú que me cargue y muestre los datos, sin necesidad de presionar nada

como por ejemplo el método doInBackground
eso es lo que quiero hacer pero supongo que es en el onCreate
ya me entenderán
si necesitan mas detalles, favor de decirlo, lo que quiero es resolver ese problemilla

Gracias a Tdos!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisando tu código veo varios detalles, principalmente los que mencionas:

**1)**

```
  selectClientes.execute(""); //Cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.String)
```

en este caso se intenta ejecutar un `Asynctask`, pero `SelectClientes`  no es un Asynctask

```
 SelectClientes selectClientes = new SelectClientes();
                selectClientes.execute(""); //Cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.String)
```

Tienes definido `SelectClientes`  como una clase que extiende de `ArrayList`

```
public class SelectClientes extends ArrayList<String>{
```

deberia ser:

```
public class SelectClientes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
```

**2)** `@Override //Method does not override method from its superclass`
Si corriges el punto anterior, todos estos métodos se van a encontrar en la clase padre Asynctask, y se solucionaría este punto.

---

Con respecto a tu pregunta:

> me busque los nombres que digite o tienen relación al edittext del nombre

La linea para obtener la referencia del EditText para el nombre esta comentada!, quita los `//`  :

```
 txtNomCli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNomCli);
```

Dentro de tu Asynctask obtienes el texto que se encuentra en el EditText:

```
 String NomCli = txtNomCli.getText().toString();
```

y debes realizar algo similar a lo que haces con el código del cliente que es obtener el valor y realizar una consulta con este.

```
String query = "Select * from clientes where nombre_cliente =" + NomCli;
```

---

Con respecto al error:

> The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.

**Es porque estas realizando un Update¿?, debes cambiar a usar el método `executeQuery()`**:

```
String query = "Select * from clientes where idcliente =" + idCliente;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
//preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Si ya me habia fijado que tenia ese Arraylist y no AnsyTask, error de novato, lo otro sobre como puedo selecionar todos los nombres que sean por ejemplo "Juan" referente al editbox, si tenia eos varios comentados ya que de ninguna froma me funciona, ni con el CodCli, ni NomCli, no se que pasa, me manda directamente a la exception, catch (Exception ex){
                    isSuccess = false;
                    result = "Verifique los Datos"; que podria deberse eso

Comment: Eso puede ser otro problema diferente, podría ser cuando realizas la conexión:  Connection con = conexionSQL.CONN(); . agrega dentro de ese catch: log.e("Error", "Este es mi problema ahora : " + ex.getMessage()); y comenta que error se registra en el LogCat, es importante que cuando implementes manejo de excepciones con try-catch imprimas el valor en el LogCat, de esta forma rápidamente puedes saber cual es el problema.

Comment: bien inserte el Log.e y me muestra lo siguiente, primero cuando introudzco el nombre a buscar por ejemplo Juan, que existe en la base de datos sale: com.sqldata.gst.appsql E/Error: Este es mi problema ahora : Invalid column name 'Oliver', entonces me fije que estaba buscando la columna de la base de datos osea el campo y no el registro, probe poner el nombre de la columna como lo tengo definido seria asi: nom_cli, y sale lo siguiente: com.sqldata.gst.appsql E/Error: Este es mi problema ahora : The executeUpdate method must not return a result set. no se a que se deba!!

Comment: Tu query debe consultar por medio del nombre no es así?, "The executeUpdate method must not return a result set" es porque estas realizando un "executeUpdate"!!! un update? es incorrecto debes realizar una consulta. Te recomiendo añadir otra pregunta ahora con estos datos y tu código.

Comment: si es correcto jejeje y como cambio ese executeUpdate, que en ves que me haga eso, me haga solo la consulta!!

Comment: Yeahh  lo logre cambie parte del codigo, que cambie, pues lo que tenia en  doInBackground, parte de ese codigo que solo hacia la consulta en segundo plano, lo agregue en la clase SelectClientes, si se pudiera agregar código aqui sin limites de caracteres os enseñara, pero bueno funciono ya me hace la consulta, lo que me hace es que despues de decirle a ese query lo siguiente: String query = "select * from clientes where nom_cli = '" + NomCli + "'";, pues me sigue buscando todos los registros y ahi solo le digo que me busque los registros referenete a nom_cli = '" + NomCli + "'", que crees?

Comment: Agregue como ejecutar tu query a mi respuesta. String query = "select * from clientes where nom_cli = '" + NomCli + "'"; el tipo de tu campo nom_cli es TEXT? para realizar una comparación así no se realiza. Te recomiendo agregues otra pregunta con este detalle.

Comment: pues ahi y cumpli tu sugerencia a ver si me ayudas aqui http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26562/ejecutar-query-mediante-editext-y-boton-a-sql-android, jeje te lo agradecere mucho!!