# Ejecutar Query Mediante Editext y Boton a SQL Android

Tags: android, sql, android-studio

Necesito saber como puedo hacer una consulta, que tipo
pues una consulta predeterminada

que cuando dijite en el edittext de mi app, un nombre de cualquier cliente
el boton buscar me traera los nombres de mi database SQL

por ejemplo estos dos tipos de consulta

```
use DB_Andro;

select * from clientes where nom_cli = 'Juan'; -- Este es el nombre que supongamos digite en el edittext

-- O ASI

SELECT * FROM clientes where nom_cli LIKE 'Juan' + '%'
```

este es mi codigo en la clase android
Ahh omitan lo que esta comentado, no es necesario en este caso:

```
package com.sqldata.gst.appsql;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Created by Administrador on 05/10/2016.
 */

public class ConClientes extends MainActivity {
    Conexion conexionSQL;
    EditText txtCdCliente, txtNomCli;
    Button btnBuscar, btnRetornar;
    ProgressBar pgrCliente;
    ListView lstClientes;
    String idCliente;
    //ResultSet rs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.con_clientes);

        conexionSQL = new Conexion();
        //txtCdCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCdCliente);
        txtNomCli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNomCli);
        btnBuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
        btnRetornar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRetornar);
        pgrCliente = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pgrCliente);
        lstClientes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstClientes);
        pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        idCliente = "";

        // Evento Ejecutar Boton
        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SelectClientes selectClientes = new SelectClientes();
                selectClientes.execute(""); //Cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.String)
            }
        });

        btnRetornar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Productos = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(Productos);
            }
        });

    }

    public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String result = "";

        List<Map<String, String>> CliList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(ConClientes.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String[] from = {"A", "B", "C"};
            int[] views = {R.id.lblClienteId, R.id.lblNomCli, R.id.lblCodCli};
            final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(ConClientes.this, CliList, R.layout.lst_cliente,
                    from, views);
            lstClientes.setAdapter(ADA);

            lstClientes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA.getItem(arg2);
                    idCliente = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String ClienName = (String) obj.get("B");
                    //String ClienCod = (String) obj.get("C"); // Tomar en Cuenta String >> int
                    txtNomCli.setText(ClienName);
                    //txtCdCliente.setText(ClienCod);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (String... params){
            try{
                Connection cnSQL = conexionSQL.CONN();
                if (cnSQL == null){
                    result = "Error en la Conexión SQL Server";
                }
                else{
                    String query = "select * from clientes";
                    PreparedStatement psSQL = cnSQL.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rsSQL = psSQL.executeQuery();

                    ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList();
                    while (rsSQL.next()){
                        Map<String, String> dataRec = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        dataRec.put("A", rsSQL.getString("idcliente"));
                        dataRec.put("B", rsSQL.getString("nom_cli"));
                        dataRec.put("C", rsSQL.getString("cod_cli"));
                        CliList.add(dataRec);
                    }
                    result = "Success";
                }
            } catch (Exception ex){
                result = "Error al Buscar Datos de la Tabla Clientes";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class SelectClientes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        String result = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        String NomCli = txtNomCli.getText().toString();
        //String CodCli = txtCdCliente.getText().toString();

        @Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r){
            pgrCliente.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(ConClientes.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (isSuccess == true){
                FillList fillList = new FillList();
                fillList.execute("");
            }
        }

        @Override //Method does not override method from its superclass
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            if (NomCli.trim().equals(""))
                result = "Favor de Introducir el Codigo del Cliente";
            else {
                try{
                    Connection con = conexionSQL.CONN();
                    if (con == null){
                        result = "No Hay Datos para Mostrar";
                    } else {
                        List<Map<String, String>> CliList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

                        String[] from = {"A", "B", "C"};
                        int[] views = {R.id.lblClienteId, R.id.lblNomCli, R.id.lblCodCli};
//                        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(ConClientes.this, CliList, R.layout.lst_cliente,
//                                from, views);
                        //lstClientes.setAdapter(ADA);

                        String query = "select * from clientes where nom_cli = '" + NomCli + "'";
                        PreparedStatement psSQL = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        ResultSet rsSQL = psSQL.executeQuery();

                        ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList();
                        while (rsSQL.next()){
                            Map<String, String> dataRec = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            dataRec.put("A", rsSQL.getString("idcliente"));
                            dataRec.put("B", rsSQL.getString("nom_cli"));
                            dataRec.put("C", rsSQL.getString("cod_cli"));
                            CliList.add(dataRec);
                        }
                        result = "Success";

//                        String query = "Select * from clientes where nom_cli =" + NomCli;
//                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
//                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); // esta es la sentencia;
//                        // se pdria poner de esta forma >>>> preparedStatement.executeQuery()
                        result = "Busqueda de Datos Correcta";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    isSuccess = false;
                    result = "Verifique los Datos";
                    Log.e("Error", "Este es mi problema ahora : " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
           return result;
        }


    }
}
```

espero que me puedan ayudar
estos son datos por si necesitan ms
la tabla es clientes
campos

```
idcliente int (1,1) primary key
nom_cli nvarchar(50)
cod_cli nvarchar(50) //Lo puse asi porque queria, ya que admite alphanumerico ejje
```

bien espero y me puedan ayudar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que realizabas anteriormente es incorrecto :

```
 String query = "select * from clientes where nom_cli = '" + NomCli + "'";
```

El operador **[like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)**, es lo que debes usar:

```
String query = "Select * from clientes where nom_cli like ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + NomCli + "%"); 

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Bro, Excelente Funciona tanto con tu metodo como con el mio, en general no era ese el problema sino que en el doInBackground de la clase FillList, ese era quien me hacia todo en la clase selectcliente solo se ejecuta el if y ya, comente todo eso uno por uno, probando y probando , primero me di cuenta que no hace nada, solo comprobar que el edittest este con datos, despues lo otro no hacia nada, la cuestion esta en el doIn Background ahora si, jejeje, a pesar de que me dabas soluciones, no eran las que necesitaba, lo corregi sin concentimiento, error de novato, pero como prog. me ayudaste!! :)